# Is there a way to generate API documentation from an AWS Lambda that's hooked to an API Gateway?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway

So I have a Typescript (without Nest just vanilla TS) AWS Lambda that's hooked to an API Gateway and I'm trying to find a way to keep its documentation updated.

I was checking if somewhere I can define in my template.yml to mention/update the resource documentation (request/response) and then from the API Gateway I can export the swagger documentation or so but there is no support for that in the template file. (Unless I missed it)

I'm wondering if there is a way to generate the documentation directly from the lambda rather than from the API Gateway as the only way I found to get it is to update the API Gateway documentation manually using the AWS' console which is very manual and not dynamic

EDIT: Update, after some more research I found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-documentationpart.html) a way to add documentation to apigateway endpoint but it means I will need to mention the location here and then re mention it in lambda part. Which can lead to the usual pitfalls of dirty programming, if I update the location of one and forget the 2nd shit will happen and it's a very bad practice

Comment: We can export swagger/openspec file with `aws apigateway get-export` , which we can probably run during deploy process and store that yaml in s3 and serve that file from lambda?

Comment: I actually was intending to do the other way around, use aws apigateway to export the documentation as swagger and save it as yaml on s3 to serve it. I'm assuming there is a way to generate swagger documentation from my lambda handler?